# Getting started with a large CRUD project in GWT? Any Caliburn-like examples?

Tags: gwt

I'm developing a client-side GWT application (the server-side API is already written). I've played around with GWT, but I've never developed a large application around it. Are there any example applications, similar to how [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/) is for WPF/Silverlight family? For managing a large project, it really got me 90% of where I needed to be. This will be a CRUD heavy application, so organization is really going to be key. It seems like I find these sort of things 6 months into a project, so I thought it'd be nice to discover it at the beginning of a project.

The closest thing I could find is this [gwt-mvp-sample](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvp-sample/), which would be unmanageable if the project grows 5x of that size (or at least to me, it seems it would be unmanageable, it could be a mistaken assumption on my part).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at solutions like ext-gwt or smartgwt? while not pure GWT, they really help with crud applications, and they both have samplers for the most common operations that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo)? I've never tried it myself but it claims to take care of a lot of the boilerplate code inherent in a Java/GWT application by generating most of it. May be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

grails will get you some crud for free. it has a gwt plugin (which you can use or not)

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same boat, trying to make relatively big application SampleMVP*20 kind of size.... i have decided to take some exceptions in the approach....i may be wrong but i think this will help me 
1. i am thinking of letting View know about the models because sending everything in generic classes is adding complexity 
2. I feel presenter also needs to know about some of the controls like ListBox , label , Datepicker etc.... its bit difficult to convert all the controls in HasValue 
3. I am also thinking of merging List and Edit Presenters for specially small pages..i will keep views separate for List and View but i will keep the one presenter... so Contact Presenter and EditPresenter will be merged.... the view widgets will be separate but i will display them on same page...like Showcase CwCellList Example.

I found showcases examples helpful you may like to give it a look...

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/